# How to open ppt in slideshow mode

Tags: macos, powerpoint

I'm able to open foo.ppt with command "open -b com.microsoft.Powerpoint foo.ppt" on Mac Terminal. But it is opened in Edit mode, how can it be opened in Slideshow mode? Thanks.

Comment: Can you send shortcut Control-Shift-S to terminal window?

Answer (score 2):

Save your presentation as a PowerPoint Show file (.ppsx or .pps). This will force PowerPoint into Slide Show when you open it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a Service in Automater. There are Presentation actions (for PP). It's very easy:

1. Under the *Presentations* actions, add *Open PowerPoint Presentation*
2. Then, add *Play PowerPoint Slide Shows*

That's it. Save the Service in Automater. It should appear in your context menu (right-click menu) when you right-click on Powerpoint files.